# How do I ignore .htaccess on subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, https

I would like to force HTTPS unless we are using the subdomain: foo.domain.com.
When I open that subdomain in my browser's incognito mode, it works. The HTTPS isn't added. When I open that subdomain on my browser in normal mode, I get an error that says: "Your connection is not private". I can see that the URL on my browser now reads: **https**://foo.domain.com. Clearing my browser's cache doesn't seem to fix it.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks ok to me. Do you see the redirect taking place. Meaning if you type in http it changes to https?

Comment: Yes, I see the http get replaced with https on the browser address bar. I updated my question to have the actual subdomain I'm trying to use. Currently, it only works for me on I open it on a private window inside Firefox.

Comment: What happens if you try another browser. Also it's not necessary to put the actual subdomain. foo is fine for example purposes. How do your subdomains work on your system? Is it a sub folder in the root directory?

Comment: It doesn't work in any other browser for me, even in "private" mode. This subdomain is an alias to an external URL. Currently, it doesn't point to resources on our local server.

Comment: That might be the cause if it doesn't really see the host in the condition being an alias. You might need to adjust the vhost config and add the the subdomain to the `ServerAlias` directive and see if that works then. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a caching problem, or an add-on such as https everywhere being mean. If it works in private browsing or incognito mode, it works in the normal mode as well. If the behaviour of private browsing/incognito mode differs from the normal mode, it means something is still cached in the normal mode or you have an add-on enabled in normal mode which you do not have enabled in private mode. I found that 301 redirects are surprisingly persistent, even persisting after deleting what I thought was all history of a certain site.

Testing your site currently seems to work fine for me. I recommend **not using 301 redirects until everything works as expected**. When everything works as expected, you can turn 302 (temporary) redirects into permanent ones as you see fit.

The following two questions from an other stackexchange site may be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects and https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox.

Comment: It works now.

Even though I had flushed the cached several times, I decided to give it a few days and see. If I had any cache issues, I figured they'd clear out.

Thanks for the help!